# How to get the standard GUI settings back

Tags: gnome, restore

Because I'm not really satisfied with the Gnome3 desktop from U18.04, I want to start experimenting. But, before I go and try all the tips and trics for Gnome3 on the internet, I want to make sure I can go back. So, what do I have to save, in order to be able to roll back any changes that I have done to the standard Ubuntu Gnome 3 desktop? I want to be able to completely restore it to it's original state. How do I do that?

Jan-80

Comment: Clone your system using Clonezilla or similar.

Comment: This is exactly what the **Timeshift** utility is for: https://www.everything-linux-101.com/blog/install-timeshift-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/back-up-the-gnome-shell-desktop-settings-linux/

Comment: @j-money: that looks like what I was looking for

Comment: @ajgringo619: a good alternative

Comment: @OrganicMarble: yes, but not very flexible

Comment: @Jan80TRS I have Timeshift running on a couple of systems, but I've never actually used it for a restore. I use Clonezilla all the time.