# Tweaking "Applications Menu" extension on Gnome3/U18.04

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-shell-extension

Following my previous question [How to get the standard GUI settings back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175124/how-to-get-the-standard-gui-settings-back) and following https://www.howtogeek.com/353819/how-to-make-ubuntu-look-more-like-windows/ , **I would like to change the appearance of the "Applications Menu" extension**. I would like to replace the text and the down arrow with a Gnome logo like this one: http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/alecive/flatwoken/512/Apps-Gnome-icon.png. I'm not looking for a complete Windows look, but 20+ years of using it, created some automatisms that are hard to shake.

distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on i3 2310M, 8GB and SSD.

Comment: HI Jan80, Can you share link to Applications Menu Extension to see what you mean..

Comment: something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxo5Q.png

Comment: Yes, PRATAP, exactly that. How did you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Workaround***

Note: I have tested it in Ubuntu 18.04, It has some side effects. Like in lock screen, or if you disable dash-to-panel extension.

Assuming your extension is located in `$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` and you have turned off the "Show Application Icon" for Dash to Panel Extension.

[image]

Open the file `$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js`

go to line numbers 420 & 421, and delete these two lines

[image]

now add below content at line number 421 like below

```
hbox.add_child(new St.Icon({ style_class: 'my-gnome-foot-print',
                               icon_name: 'view-app-grid-symbolic' }));
```

[image]

Now Observe that "Applications ↓" is replaced with `view-app-grid-symbolic` system icon.

save the work and relax.

Now you can play with the `.css` file as you wish.

Open the file `stylesheet.css` from `$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com` and paste below content at the end of already existing text like below

```
.my-gnome-foot-print {
color: transparent;
background-image: url("my-gnome-foot-print.svg");
background-size: contain; }
```

[image]

your image must be present in the extensions folder as visible in the above image.

[image]

One of the side effect that is lock screen problem is not seen when this extension is placed in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` and dash-to-panel extension is used.

Comment: Very nice. But a lot of work.

Comment: yes.. lot 0f work..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Arc Menu on Gnome3]I solved the problem by abandoning the Applications extension altogether, and I chose the "Arc menu" extension for Gnome3. It starts out with an icon on the button, but you can use your own. I took the Ubuntu logo, like Windows uses its logo for a start button.
On top of that, the extension has it's own customizing menu, and it also contains the shutdown, lock and logout buttons, things that the Applications extension didn't have.

Comment: Good, but not as such an answer to the question, which is "Tweaking Application extension.

Comment: My own answer is: use something else. 
Blunt maybe, but there are so many possibilities, that that seems to me a valid solution to my original problem, wich was to make Gnome3behave/look more like Windaws.

Comment: Then think of asking the question that way. Now, this became an XY problem. Instead of asking your real issue, where others could have come up with this or other suggestions, you ask about a way you thought of solving the problem.

Comment: Excuse me for the mixup.

Comment: Please accept the answer of @YuganTej, which answered the question as you asked it. It is a convoluted solution, but there is no other way, so it is the right answer to the question as asked.